# Stream.Seek behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I came across this earlier today that was not sure why it happens.

I have the following code that sets the internal position of the file stream to a location so I can read the number of lines from that position. It is similar to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265639/net-c-sharp-random-access-in-text-files-no-easy-way) but when I used `stream.Seek` I see strange results

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
using(var stream = _streamFactory.CreateStream())
using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, _streamFactory.Encoding))
{
     stream.Seek(startPosition, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

     string value;
     for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
     {
         if ((value = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             b.AppendLine(value);
         }
      }
 }
```

Now what I am doing is reading a file using the UTF-8 encoding so I know there are extra bits at the start of the file that denote this but are not part of the text I want to extract.

Say for eample I have the following text in the file

```
Hello my name is bob
```

So if I set `startPosition` to 0 my results will be  **Hello my name is bob** however when I set `startPosition` to 1 I dont get **ello my name is bob** but rather **@@Hello my name is bob** where @@ are 2 bytes from the encoding bits.

So my question is why when I set `.Seek(0)` and then do a `ReadLine` I get the correct line but `Seek(1)` will return the 2nd and 3rd bytes of the encoding?

`Seek(3)` will also yield the same results as `Seek(0)`. If this was consistent I would have thought `Seek(0)` would return **@@@Hello my name is bob**

Also how do I know how many extra bytes are at the start of the file without reading it (but knowing the encoding)?

I tried looking at the disassembled code and had to stop before my brain went on strike.

*Note:*
The Streambuilder in this case is just creating a `FileStream`. I do this so I can Unit test this code using a `MemoryStream`

Answer (score 1):

First two bytes represent the encoding of file. Take a look at [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm) article.

Comment: Yes I realize that my question was why doesn't `Seek(0)` include those 2 bytes when doing a `ReadLine`?